# Manipulate time on System.DateTime object

Tags: powershell

I have an small *(probably)* problem in a function that i am writing. The input to the function is two *(start & stop)* of the type System.DateTime acquired by the function Get-Date. The output is an array of System.DateTime objects (*start & stop)* that are between the input objects. Ie.

```
Start   Stop
2018-01-14 13:54:15 2018-01-14 13:54:15
2018-01-15 13:54:15 2018-01-15 13:54:15
```

Works. However in the process of building this array i need to manipulate the time on the start and stop object and to be honest i havent the slightest clue as to how to set the hour, minute and second on an existing object. Desired output is Ie.

```
Start   Stop
2018-01-14 08:00    2018-01-14 17:00
2018-01-15 08:00    2018-01-15 17:00
```

I've tried using the ParseExact method but it touches the date as well. I can probably send in more than the time to it, but that seems like 'code from hell' ...

```
PS C:\tmp> (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

den 10 januari 2018 14:07:13


PS C:\tmp> [datetime](Get-Date).AddDays(-7)::ParseExact("09:00","hh:mm",$null)

den 17 januari 2018 09:00:00


PS C:\tmp>
```

**How on earth can i manipulate the time, and only the time, on an existing System.DateTime object?**

As the function itself serves no real value to the problem it has been excluded.

Comment: `ParseExact()` is a static method of the `DateTime` *class*, not of `DateTime` *objects*. You can't call it like that. Also, you "need to manipulate the time" ... *how*?

Comment: The DateTime object sent into the function *(either start or stop)* has the current time i need to change it to 8AM for the start and 5PM for the stop. This is for further processing fetching metrics for VMs during workhours where i need fetch the metric day by day since off hours gives missleading metrics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Date` portion of the timestamp, then add the desired number of hours (8 for 8AM, 17 for 5PM):

```
PS> (Get-Date).Date.AddHours(8)

den 17 januari 2018 08:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks! Knew it was a small problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

your question is not very clear is it what you're looking for ?

```
$date1=[datetime]"2018-01-14 13:54:15"
PS>$date1.AddSeconds(-15)

Sunday, January 14, 2018 1:54:00 PM
```

Comment: Added some more information *(edit)*. Don't really know how to describe it better.